# Laravel Eloquent model with sqlsrv is changing the table names

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm new to laravel and have a problem with the model created with `php artisan make:model [Name]`

In my case i connect to the sqlsrv. The connection is established.

my route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/tasks', function () {
    // $tasks = DB::table('WebShops')->get(); //This is working
    $tasks = App\WebShops::all(); //This is not working
    dd($tasks);
});
```

my datatable:
Webshops
[image]

For this i created a model to connect to the database. `php artisan make:model Webshops`.

When i access the db with the command `$tasks = App\WebShops::all();` i'm getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Invalid Object Name "web_shops". (SQL: select * from
>   [web_shops]).

The problem is that ma table name is different. The query is searching where the table is web_shops and my table name is Webshop. I don't understand it.

Comment: Okey the solution fot this is to add the table in Model. `protected $table = ....`

Answer (score 1):

the name in the db not write. you can't write 2 words behind each other like that als db name allows plural.

to avoid such problem you when you make model you can write like that

php artisan make:model Wenshop -c -m -r

when you write like that Laravel make for you Model+ Migration+ Controller with the right names